# Ruby 'Digest' doesn't create correct hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I am attempting to create a login system, though a very weird output is being made instead of what is expected. Instead of creating a proper hash, it spews a random jumble of unicode. Whilst my code example uses SHA256, all other hashes I can create also do this.

```
    puts "Hello, welcome to CORIS. Please set up an account."
    print "Username | "
    user = gets.chomp
    print "\nPass | "
    pass = gets.chomp
    userFile = File.open("user.keys", 'a+')
    passFile = File.open("pass.keys", 'a+')
    userFile.write(user)
    passer = Digest::SHA256.digest "#{pass}"
    puts passer
    sleep(50)
```

Output:

```
Loading CORIS.
Hello, welcome to CORIS. Please set up an account.
Username | zero

Pass | TheCorruption
F��
�ib�LoIe[�jN��u�b���#r�K��
```

Digest::MD5.digest Output:

```
Loading CORIS.
Hello, welcome to CORIS. Please set up an account.
Username | zero

Pass | TheCorruption
�/�7dw{�:�A�����
```

I've reinstalled the gem, any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `digest` methods aren't returning random jumbles of unicode, they're returning proper hashes in binary format. If you want to see a "readable" version then [`hexdigest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-hexdigest) or [`base64digest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-base64digest):

```
Digest::SHA256.digest('pancakes')
# => "\xD0@;\xE2\x99\x9CH\x99\xEF:>=f\xD5]\xF4h\x9F\x7F\xC5~\xBF\x8A\xB5yu\x94\x92M\x12O\x99" 
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('pancakes')
# => "d0403be2999c4899ef3a3e3d66d55df4689f7fc57ebf8ab5797594924d124f99" 
Digest::SHA256.base64digest('pancakes')
# => "0EA74pmcSJnvOj49ZtVd9Giff8V+v4q1eXWUkk0ST5k="
```

Comment: I should have added, but comparing the hash against itself would yield false, but this is a solution to the problem so I'll mark it as such.